# Parts of markdown code turns green by themselfs

Tags: markdown

I'm coding a page in markdown and some parts of examples in ~~~php example ~~~ turns green without any purpouse.

Example:

```
    Check out a specific version:

~~~php
svn co http://svn.doctrine-project.org/branches/1.2 .
~~~
```

Afterwards, the code looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeTUN.png

Any idea how to cancel the green color?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking Markdown to use PHP syntax highlighting, but your code snippet isn't PHP. [In PHP `//` indicates a line comment](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php). As a result, most of your URL is treated as a comment.

Here is a similar example on Stack Overflow:

```php
<?php
svn co http://svn.doctrine-project.org/branches/1.2 .
```

We use grey, not green, but the issue is the same.

By not requesting PHP highlighting your problem should go away.

In standard Markdown your code block would be indented by four spaces and nothing would be highlighted. GitHub-Flavored Markdown and others use backticks. I'm not sure what version you're using where tildes are used to indicate code, but this will probably work:

```
~~~
svn co http://svn.doctrine-project.org/branches/1.2 .
~~~
```